# How to give smooth edges when filling a png with color in OpenGl/GLES

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, shader

[image: Right one is the orginal and left one is sampled by fragment shader]

this is my fragment shader

```
 #ifdef GL_ES
 #define LOWP lowp
 precision mediump float;
 #else
 #define LOWP  
 #endif
 varying LOWP vec4 v_color;
 varying vec2 v_texCoords;
 uniform sampler2D u_texture;
 void main()
 {
        vec4 final_color = v_color * texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);
   if (final_color.w != 0.0){
                final_color = v_color;
   }

   gl_FragColor = final_color;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your original image is anti-aliased. Try just using the color of `v_color` with the alpha from the texture:

```
gl_FragColor.xyz = v_color.xyz;
gl_FragColor.w = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords).w;
```

Comment: Oops - not quite want I meant to write though. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (final_color.w >= 0.0){
    final_color.w = clamp(final_color.w, 0.0,1.0);
    final_color.xyz = v_color.xyz;
}

    gl_FragColor = final_color;
```

I figured out I can also use this but @GuyRT's way is more efficient